# How to get a Hightlight below some text using CSS

Tags: html, css, sass

I want to create a CSS class that I can attach to a span with some text, to create a highlight like so:
[image]

Would it be possible to make it relative to the font size of the span? so that I can use a common class. Can it be done using the psuedo selector like :after, or the  element?

Any help is much appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```css
body
{
  white-space: pre;
  font-family: system-ui;
  font-weight: bold;
}

h1
{
  margin: 0;
}
.mark,
mark
{
  background-color: transparent;
  position: relative;
}
.mark:before,
mark:before
{
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 40%;
  background-color: #FAC86B;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0.5em;
  mix-blend-mode: overlay;
}
```

```html
<span class="mark">AI MARKETPLACE</span>
<h1 class="container">
<mark>AI MARKETPLACE</mark>
AI MARKETPLACE
test <mark>text</mark> blah
AI MARKETPLACE
<mark>test text blah</mark>
</h1>
```

Comment: I guess.. this is what he is looking for Good job !